# Why doesn't python show error at the first time and only show at the second time?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a small function using python's `os module` to detect my android's storage and return `True or False`. I'm running on linux and this is my code and note that the reason I added `print statements` is to make sure everything is okey.

```
import os


def usb_detect(path):
    for usb in os.listdir(path):   # Before accessing usb storages, we have to access into mtp:host= blah
        if not os.listdir(os.path.join(path,usb)):  # Now we try to access the usb device and show it's storages
           print(os.listdir(os.path.join(path,usb)))
           return False
        else:
           print(os.listdir(os.path.join(path,usb)))
           return True


print(usb_detect(path='/run/user/1000/gvfs/'))
```

**I have tried these**

When I connect my android with usb,set to `File Transfer` and run the `first time`, it shows a list containing my android's storage and `True`. When I set to `No file transfer`, it shows this error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/yemankyaw/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/usb_access.py", line 24, in <module>
print(usb_detect(path='/run/user/1000/gvfs/'))
File "/home/yemankyaw/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/usb_access.py", line 16, in usb_detect
if not os.listdir(os.path.join(path,usb)):  # Now we try to access the usb device and show it's storages
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error: '/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=Android_Android_86bb9bfe0005'
```

but when I run again without changing setting, the error is gone and the program shows `empty list` and `False` as expected.

In fact, runing the `first time` in either `File Transfer Mode` or `No Transfer Mode` won't show the error, but when I set to another mode and run the `second time`, it will show the `error`. Then if I run again without changing setting, the error is gone forever until I change mode.

I thought changing to another mode and running immediately might be the cause of error but I waited, it's not. Whenever I changed to another mode, it shows error.

Comment: Are you deliberately returning in the loop after processing one element?

Comment: Are you surprised that you get an error when you tell your phone not to act as a file sharing device?

Comment: I'm a beginner and I don't actually get what you say in the first comment but I mean even if it shows the error, why did It disappeared when I rerun the second time. And the error comes out not the time only in 'No Transfer Mode' , whenever change to another mode and run, it shows the error.

Comment: Your return statement triggers on the first device: your loop doesn't run after that. It seems that you only have one device, but you may actually have more. Try catching the error and continuing the loop.